# Facebook Graph feed does not contain reply to comments

Tags: facebook-fql

We are fishing posts, comments and so on for clients that have business pages on Facebook using the feed. Now Facebook permits business pages to reply to comments. Sadly in the feed, the replies to the comments are not included. Does anyone know how to include these in the feed?

I can't believe that we need to make a call for each comment one by one to Facebook using `FQL` or similar just to know if it has replies.

Any information is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the post id to get all the comments-

```
select text from comment where post_id=
```